# Nginx HTTPS redirect exception

Tags: nginx

I am developing a new project that uses forced HTTPS navigation where we need to display an iframe with content that is not HTTPS.

Issue comes that in Nginx I am forcing the usage of HTTPS with a redirect for any request.

I want to add an "exception" in the rewrite for the URL demo.html, I have no clue how to do this properly, any help much appreciated. Thanks

This is our Nginx config file:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen       [::]:80;
    server_name
        www.domain.com
        domain.com
      ;
    rewrite        ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
    listen       443 ssl spdy;
    listen       [::]:443 ssl spdy;
    server_name
        www.domain.com
        domain.com
      ;

    ### redirect www to no www with client code 301 ###
    if ($host = 'www.domain.com') {
        rewrite  ^/(.*)$  https://domain.com/$1  permanent;
    }

    root   /srv/users/public;

    proxy_set_header    Host              $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-SSL   on;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
index index.php;

# Don't serve hidden files.
location ~ /\. {
    deny all;
}

location /
{
    try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
  include       fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

  fastcgi_param KOHANA_ENV PRODUCTION;

  fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:2222;

  try_files     $uri =404;
}
```

Comment: Hows your demo.html url looks like?

Comment: Hello, will be http://domain.com/demo.html?param=1&param=2 OR in case is easier domain.com/domain/demo/6 (6 == numeric), thanks a lot!

Comment: At the end I will disable the HTTPS redirect for all and allow browsing also witohut the HTTPS.

Comment: So what I did is to force the homepage to be HTTPS and the rest of link I print they are always HTTPS except that one I need that doesnt use HTTPS. I did this: ## we only force the HTTPS to the home page but we allow to browse without HTTPS if they want to.
    if ($request_uri = /) { 
      set $test  A; 
    } 
    if ($scheme = 'http') { 
      set $test  "${test}B"; 
    } 
    if ($test = AB) { 
        rewrite  ^/(.*)$  https://yclas.com/$1  permanent;
    } 
    ## END if Hack

Answer (score 1):

At the end I will disable the HTTPS redirect for all and allow browsing also without the HTTPS.

So what I did is to force the homepage to be HTTPS and the rest of link I print they are always HTTPS except that one I need that doesnt use HTTPS. I did this: ## we only force the HTTPS to the home page but we allow to browse without HTTPS if they want to.

```
## we only force the HTTPS to the home page but we allow to browse without HTTPS if they want to.
if ($request_uri = /) { 
  set $test  A; 
} 
if ($scheme = 'http') { 
  set $test  "${test}B"; 
} 
if ($test = AB) { 
    rewrite  ^/(.*)$  https://yclas.com/$1  permanent;
} 
## END if Hack
```